# OracleChangeNotifications registering improperly in .NET Core 5.0

Tags: .net, database, oracle, .net-core, f#

I have some code written in F#, using .NET Core and ASP.NET Core. It's supposed to register change listeners to the database, and it does work occasionally:

```ml
namespace Raptor.ChangeListener.Oracle

open System
open System.Data

open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
open Microsoft.Extensions.Options

open Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

open Raptor.ChangeListener


[<Sealed>]
type OracleChangeListenerOptions() =
    member val ConnectionString = Unchecked.defaultof<string>   with get, set
    member val Query            = Unchecked.defaultof<string>   with get, set
    member val Timeout          = Unchecked.defaultof<TimeSpan> with get, set


type OracleChangeListener(options: OracleChangeListenerOptions IOptions, logger: ILogger<OracleChangeListener>) =
    let options = options.Value

    let mutable disposed = false
    let sync = obj()
    let mutable handlers: (Guid * Action) list = []

    let mutable connection: OracleConnection = null
    let mutable command   : OracleCommand    = null
    let mutable dependency: OracleDependency = null

    let startup =
        async {
            connection <- new OracleConnection(options.ConnectionString)
            connection.StateChange.Add(fun state ->
                if not disposed then
                    match state.CurrentState with
                    | ConnectionState.Broken -> logger.LogError(sprintf "Connection Broken: %s" options.Query)
                    | ConnectionState.Closed -> logger.LogError(sprintf "Connection Closed: %s" options.Query)
                    | _                      -> ()
                )

            do! connection.OpenAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask


            command    <- new OracleCommand(options.Query, connection)
            dependency <- new OracleDependency(command)

            // these don't exist without first setting the dependency
            command.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce <- false
            command.Notification.Timeout        <- int64 options.Timeout.TotalSeconds
            let test = (command, dependency)

            dependency.OnChange.Add(fun state ->
                if not disposed then
                    try
                        logger.LogInformation(
                            let info = state.Info.ToString()
                            let typ  = state.Type.ToString()
                            sprintf "%s Notification Change Type: %s, TableName: %A" info typ state.ResourceNames
                            )

                        for _, handler in handlers do
                            try
                                handler.Invoke()
                            with ex ->
                                logger.LogError(ex, "OracleChangeListener handler error")

                    with ex ->
                        logger.LogError(ex, "OracleChangeListener error")
                )

            match command.ExecuteNonQuery() with
            | -1 -> ()
            |  n -> failwithf "Error Code In Listener: %i" n
            }
        |> Async.StartAsTask

    interface IChangeListener with
        member _.AddHandler handler =
            lock sync (fun () ->
                let key = Guid.NewGuid()
                handlers <- List.append handlers [(key, handler)] 
                key
                )

        member _.RemoveHandler key =
            lock sync (fun () ->
                handlers <- handlers |> List.where (fun (k, _) -> k <> key)
                )


    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() =
            if not disposed then
                disposed <- true // flag early for internal checks
                if not (isNull dependency) then dependency.RemoveRegistration(connection)
                if not (isNull command   ) then command   .Dispose()
                if not (isNull connection) then connection.Dispose()
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this)


[<Sealed>]
type OracleChangeListener<'TCategory>(options, logger) =
    inherit OracleChangeListener(options, logger)
    interface IChangeListener<'TCategory>
```

when I select from `DBA_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS` in the database, I see all the proper registrations in place:

[image: valid registrations]

But more often than not, and I can't determine what the cause of this is, the registrations are made with a port of -1 instead of a valid port number, like so:

[image: invalid registrations]

When this happens, none of the services are properly notified when registered tables are changed. Additionally, all invalid rows are cleared when a change that ought to trigger a notification occurs.